# Bigquery missed one day data

Tags: google-bigquery

Today(8.23 T 15:00), I found that there is no 8.22 data sheet at all.

no 22 datasheet

[image]

The intraday data has become 23

intraday datasheet

[image]
so what's the problem, does google miss the data?

Comment: file feature requests and/or bug reports at [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0)

Comment: Thanks, Mikhail. Currrently, it already fixed, I will file to the tracker next time.